# How can I add CKEditor on a Collection - Symfony 6, CKEditor 2.4

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, symfony-forms

I'm working on Symfony and I want to add CKEditor on a TextType in a `CollectionType`.

Let me explain the situation: I've already used CKEditor somewhere else on the website and it's working perfectly. But now, I need to add that editor to another field called `CollectionType`.

So, I don't have any errors but when I click on my 'add' button to add a new Anecdote it's calling a simple `TextAreaType` not CKEditor. I don't know how to deal, I guess, with the JS to call the good thing.

I hope that my issue is clear! Now, I will show you my code.

That's my TWIG code :

```
<h1>{{ action }}</h1>
{{ form_start(form) }}
[...]
<div id="anecdotes" data-prototype="{{ form_row(form.anecdotes.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
    {{ form_row(form.anecdotes) }}
    <span></span>
</div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Now my Javascript code making my collection work the way I want :

```js
let collection, addButton, span;
window.onload = () => {
  collection = document.querySelector("#anecdotes");
  span = collection.querySelector("span");
  addButton = document.createElement("button");
  addButton.className = "add-anecdote btn";
  addButton.innerText = "Ajouter une anecdote";

  let newBtn = span.append(addButton);

  collection.dataset.index = collection.querySelectorAll("input").length;

  addButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    addNewButton(collection, newBtn);
  });
};

function addNewButton(collection, newBtn) {
  let prototype = collection.dataset.prototype;
  let index = collection.dataset.index;
  prototype = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

  let content = document.createElement("html");
  content.innerHTML = prototype;
  let newForm = content.querySelector("div");
  let deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
  deleteBtn.type = "button";
  deleteBtn.className = "btn btn-red";
  deleteBtn.id = "delete-anecdote-" + index;
  deleteBtn.innerText = "Supprimer cette anecdote";

  newForm.append(deleteBtn);

  collection.dataset.index++;

  let addBtn = collection.querySelector(".add-anecdote");

  span.insertBefore(newForm, addBtn);

  deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.previousElementSibling.parentElement.remove();
  });
}
```

Then, my Form Type calls my collection :

```php
$builder
[...]
->add('anecdotes', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => AnecdoteType::class,
    'label' => 'Anecdotes',
    'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
]);
```

And the form called by the code just before :

```php
$builder
    ->add('title', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Titre'])
    ->add('description', CKEditorType::class, ['label' => 'Anecdote']);
```

**EDIT:**
Now, I added at the end of my script, in  the `addNewButton` method:

```js
Object.create(document.querySelector('.ckeditor'),{
    toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', '|', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'blockQuote' , "insertTable", 'undo', 'redo'],
})
```

And in my forms :

```php
->add('anecdotes', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => AnecdoteType::class,
    'label' => 'Anecdotes',
    'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
    'attr'=> ['class' => 'ckeditor']
])

$builder
->add('title', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Titre'])
->add('description', CKEditorType::class, ['label' => 'Anecdote', 'attr' => ['class'=>'ckeditor']]);
```

But when I'm looking into the inspector of my navigator I have :

[image: screenshot of my navigator]

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the fields are added dynamically, so when you initialize the CkEditor you still don't have the fields available.

In your AnecdoteType form you can add a class to the description field like so ->add('description', TextareaType::class, ['label' => 'Anecdote', 'attr' => [
'class' => 'ckeditor'
],])

Then in your javascript code you create the ckeditor instance in your method to add the dynamic fields at the end of the method

ClassicEditor
.create(document.querySelector('.ckeditor'), {
toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', '|', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'blockQuote' , "insertTable", 'undo', 'redo'],
})
.then(editor => {
console.log(Array.from(editor.ui.componentFactory.names()));
})
.catch(error => {
console.error(error);
});

something like this and in this way whenever you add a field you will create the CkEditor instance

Comment: Ok ! Thank you for your advices.
I tried but I don't know on which element I can link the .create().

Comment: addNewButton al final de este método

Comment: I make some changes but it still not working, I edit my post with new informations. Please check them ! Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem. The problem lives in the data-prototype, ckeditor uses script tags to convert the text area in ckeditor. The only problem is when you dynamically inject a script in the innerHTML, it is not interpreted, you have to go and get the scripts to evaluate them or create a script tag and inject it back in the dom to be evaluated.